# Return object adhering to typeclass from method

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have a typeclass for Path's. It contains an enlarge method (the path is being enlarged by moving around vertices), which should be able to return any type that again adheres to the Path typeclass. I figured something like this should work (data members removed for simplicity):

```
case class Circle()
case class Polyline()
trait Path[T] {
  /// Note how the return type T2 should again have a Path[T2] typeclass
  def enlarge[T2 : Path](path : T) : T2
}

object Path {
  implicit object PathCircle extends Path[Circle] {
    def enlarge[T2 : Path](path : Circle) = Polyline()
  }
  implicit object PathPolyline extends Path[Polyline] {
    def enlarge[T2 : Path](path : Polyline) = Polyline()
  }
}

object Test {
  import Path._

  implicitly[Path[Circle]].enlarge(Circle())
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
[error] test.scala:12: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Polyline
[error]  required: T2
[error]  Note: implicit object PathPolyline is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[error]     def enlarge[T2 : Path](path : Circle) = Polyline()
[error]                                                     ^
[error] test.scala:15: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Polyline
[error]  required: T2
[error]     def enlarge[T2 : Path](path : Polyline) = Polyline()
[error]                                                       ^
[error] test.scala:22: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both object PathPolyline in object Path of type Path.PathPolyline.type
[error]  and object PathCircle in object Path of type Path.PathCircle.type
[error]  match expected type Path[T2]
[error]   implicitly[Path[Circle]].enlarge(Circle())
[error]                                   ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're letting the caller pick the return type—e.g. what should happen if I call `PathCircle.enlarge[Circle](Circle())`?

Comment: Currently I have a Conv[T] typeclass, that can convert the Polyline returned from the enlarge method into a user specified type (in your case Circle). However, you are right that this is really not the right way to go about it. Maybe there is a different way to specify that the return type should have a Path typeclass for it?

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of trial and error, I came up with a solution that seems to work.
Essentially one can return a PathBox object, which is a wrapper object for both the returned Path instance and its implicit Path typeclass evidence. Couple that with implementations of the actual typeclass for the PathBox, and you get a return parameter that again has the typeclass implemented for it.
Only issue that I have with the solution, is that the individual typeclass implementations can not have circular dependencies, but I can live with that, for now.
Code:

```
case class Circle()
case class CircleArc()
case class Polyline()

/// A container storing both an object adhering to an EnlargablePath
/// typeclass, plus the instance of the typeclass itself
case class PathBox[T](val t : T)(implicit val tInst : EnlargablePath[T])

/// Any path that can be enlarged and potentially return a new kind of
/// path, which still adheres to the EnlargablePath typeclass however
trait EnlargablePath[T] {
  def enlarge[_](path : T) : PathBox[_]
}

object EnlargablePath  {

  // A Polyline can always return a larger polyline
  implicit object PathPolyline extends EnlargablePath[Polyline] {
    def enlarge[_](path : Polyline) = PathBox(Polyline())
  }

  // Enlarging a circle only req. a new radius, so it returns a circle
  implicit object PathCircle extends EnlargablePath[Circle] {
    def enlarge[_](path : Circle) = PathBox(Circle())
  }

  // Enlarging a CircleArc, results in a full circle. This actually
  // requires the PathCircle object to be defined before!
  implicit object PathCircleArc extends EnlargablePath[CircleArc] {
    def enlarge[_](path : CircleArc) = PathBox(Circle())
  }

  // Make sure that a PathBox[_] can also be treated as an EnlargablePath
  implicit def PathPathBox[T] = new EnlargablePath[PathBox[T]] {
    def enlarge[_](pathBox : PathBox[T]) = pathBox.tInst.enlarge(pathBox.t)
  }

  // For nicer syntax, any object that implements the EnlargablePath
  // typeclass gets its methods added. If you care about performance,
  // take a look at spire's (the scala math library) macros for this
  // purpose
  implicit class EnlargablePathOps[T : EnlargablePath](val p : T) {
    def enlarge = implicitly[EnlargablePath[T]].enlarge(p)
  }
}

object Test {
  import EnlargablePath._

  println(Circle().enlarge)
  println(Circle().enlarge.enlarge)
  println(Circle().enlarge.enlarge.enlarge)
}
```

Comment: The only problem is that `Circle().enlarge` returns a type `PathBox[_]`. I was working on this earlier, didn't get what I wanted but I'll upload my idea shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This is based off of this talk about type-level programming (well worth watching)

> [Academese to English: Scala's Type System, Dependent Types and What It Means To You](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptCvn4-lyXM#t=1568)

```
case class Circle()
case class Polyline()

// This is our type class.
// More type parameters could be added if more functions were added.
trait Path[T,E]{
  def enlarge(p:T):E
}

object Path {
  implicit object PathCircle extends Path[Circle,Polyline] {
    override def enlarge(path : Circle): Polyline = Polyline()
  }
  implicit object PathPolyline extends Path[Polyline,PolyLine] {
    override def enlarge(path : Polyline) = Polyline()
  }
  def enlarge[T,E](path:T)(implicit tp:Path[T,E]):E = tp.enlarge(path)
}

object Test {
  import Path._

  // The easist way to call it
  val pl: Polyline = Path.enlarge(Circle())

  // Or since we're already importing Path
  val pl2: Polyline = enlarge(Circle())
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that our return type can be very specific. This can only be good thing!

---

I was initially trying to get it to work with type members:

```
trait Path[T] {
  type E 
  def enlarge(path : T) : E
}
...
implicit object PathCircle extends Path[Circle] {
  type E = Circle
  ...
```

But this just gave the return type.

```
val pl:Path[Circle]#E = enlarge(Circle())
```